# filtering a numpy matrix using a dataframe column which is a boolean column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where one column is a booelan column, there are n rows in my dataframe. I am trying to use this column to filter a numpy matrix which is n by 30.

> filtered_matrix = my_matrix[df['my_bool_col'], :]

The error I get is

> IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 30 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1

Comment: a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  would be helpful

Comment: Try to transpose the index from a column to a line..

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you want to index a dumpy matrix based on boolean values within a data frame. For this, you could do something like this:

```
filtered_matrix = my_matrix[np.where([df['my_bool_col'].astype(int) == 1), :]
```

Numpy's `np.where()` method (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) in this case will return indices where an entry is `True`, then you use this array of indices to then index your matrix.